# Buscar frase dentro de arquivos .cs de uma pasta especifica usando C#

Tags: c#, arquivo, algoritmo-de-busca

Gostaria de saber como eu consigo buscar uma frase dentro de arquivos .cs de uma pasta específica.

Não precisa desenvolver código, só gostaria de saber qual/quais funções usar e como usá-las. Não consegui achar nada relacionado no Google.

Comment: Você usa alguma IDE?

Comment: Tô usando o Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode usar as classes [DirectoryInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.directoryinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) e [FileInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx), da seguinte maneira:

```
 DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\projetos\projeto\src");
 foreach (FileInfo arquivo in dirInfo.GetFiles("*.cs", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
 {
    string codigoCSharp = File.ReadAllText(arquivo.FullName);
    if (codigoCSharp.Contains("Minha Frase"))
        Console.WriteLine("Encontrado");
 }
```

Comment: E como ficaria se dentro desta pasta "C:\projetos\projeto\src" eu tivesse subpastas das quais quisesse adicionar à pesquisa?

Comment: Utilize `SearchOption.AllDirectories` no segundo parâmetro do método `GetFiles` . Editei a resposta.

Comment: Era isso que eu procurava! Obrigado pela resposta, foi de grande ajuda.